# Salesforce AppExchange - How is app popularity measured?

Tags: appexchange, app

**I'm interested to know how popularity is measured on the Salesforce AppExchange?**

For example I have a [free app listed](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N3000000B4pbAEAR), which is currently at popularity position 152 in the free category. It has 45 installs, 4 5* star reviews, and has been out for 10 days, it has 7 tweets and 0 fLikes... but it is difficult to know which factors make it more popular.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its primarily depends on number of installs over a given time period.
We cannot say that it depends on the app purchases as the most popular apps aren't purchased as they are free.
Good reviews means app install growth as majority of users install the app after reading reviews.So mainly installs over a given time period are the main factor of app popularity.

Comment: Thanks for the response, do you have any further understandng of the "given time period"? When viewing popular listings or categories ordered by popularity, there is no time period to set. Is the popularity measured in "all time" or within a set period?

Comment: Popularity ratings on AppExchange changes are shown every 24 hours ( updated after every 24 hours) as far as i have seen .In my company we generally monitor our apps popularity every 15 days of time frame .So in our case given time is 15 days.

Comment: @Sagar Where does your information come from? Keen to see some references.